# How to rearrange the sample order of a torch dataloader?

Tags: python, sorting, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I have a "torch.utils.data.DataLoader". I want to rearrange the order of the samples. Is it possible?

Comment: By rearrange, do you mean shuffle at every epoch? You can set `shuffle=True` to achieve this.

Comment: But I don't want to randomly shuffle them. I want to re order them in a particular way.

Comment: @JakeTae But I don't want to randomly shuffle them. I want to re order them in a particular way.

Comment: Then you have to reorder the `Dataset` which is used to initialize the `Dataloader`. Your custom `Dataset` class should have an `__getitem__` method, which determines the order of how the samples are retrieved.

Comment: @JakeTae Yes it is there. Is there any code example that I can see? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `torch.utils.data.Subset` and specify the indices.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Subset, TensorDataset


data = np.arange(5) ** 2
dataset = TensorDataset(torch.tensor(data))

# Subset with entire Dataset in rearranged order
dataset_ordered = Subset(dataset, indices=[2, 1, 3, 4, 0])

for x in DataLoader(dataset_ordered):
    print(x)

# [tensor([4])]
# [tensor([1])]
# [tensor([9])]
# [tensor([16])]
# [tensor([0])]
```